# Requesting details leading to termination

Tags: termination, autism-spectrum

I was recently terminated from my job due to

> "concerns raised about your behavior and comments by various people who work with you".

I think the problems which raised these concerns are somewhat rooted in my autism.  I would like to receive details so that I can work on these items with my therapist.  To that end I sent a message to my supervisor

> I got the termination letter today, which only mentioned I was terminated due to behavior and comments.  I do not see my therapist until September 6, so could I get a list of any and all complaints and behavior examples from yesterday’s meeting and the previous one so I can work on them with my therapist when I next see her?

How likely is it I will receive a response, and how long should I expect it to take?  I have yet to hear even a confirmation that they will do that.

Edit: I live in Iowa.

Follow up:  I received a response this morning.  Going over the reasons still seems silly to me, but Iowa is one of those states they don't need a reason to terminate, so...

Comment: what country/state are you in?

Comment: I suppose that strongly depends on your supervisor. They may even not reply to you at all.. or they *could* reply and give you those improvements.

Comment: Presumably not very likely, but you've already sent the message, so any answers here would mostly come down to speculating what your supervisor will do, which isn't exactly a good fit for this site.

Comment: It is doubtful - they're not going to give you anything which could be remotely interpreted to be the basis of a lawsuit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on the nation/state you are in, it's anywhere from unlikely to **zero chance**.  If they let you go due to autistic behaviors, they will say **zero**.

It's a sad, nasty, but true thing that autistics are discriminated against.  You'll never be fired for having autism, but "someone complained about your behavior" or "you have been found to have violated obscure rule 84279-31B".

Do what you can to mitigate your symptoms and find another employer.  Sounds to me you are better off.  If you want honest advice, go to a friend.

Comment: I guess it's worth pointing out the obvious: your employer won't ever state that you were fired for having autism because autism could be construed as a disability making you a member of a protected class (at least in the US), which could lead to potential lawsuits.

Comment: Even admitting that the firing reasons might be something the OP should discuss with their therapist could be legally risky.

Comment: @colbin8r of course not, you just violated obscure rule 84279-31B.  They'd never fire you for being autistic </sarcasm>

Comment: Termination reasons are as vague as they can make them like "didn't fit into the culture", "attitude issues", "quality of work",etc. They'd **like** to terminate you with vague cause, but what they're hoping for is no more than having to have the person be allowed to collect unemployment. It'll make their insurance go up perhaps but they're not getting sued.

Comment: Can you please clarify @PatriciaShanahan?

Comment: @traisjames At least in the US, the employer has to avoid any appearance of firing someone for a disability without having tried to make reasonable accommodations.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan and the ways they get around it....

Answer (score 7):

It's not a direct answer to your question, but it kind of is.

As Richard states, you're not going to get a response.  I agree. So in lieu of just chiming in, I'd like to suggest what you can do next.

Find your government agency that handles disability discrimination issues and file a complaint. Depending on a number of factors, your response will vary but I think it's worth doing, if for no other reason than that company needs to have the complaint in their government file for when this happens again.

The question whether you can help yourself by doing this or not is unanswerable. However, getting them under some regulatory scrutiny can help someone that comes after you.

For the next job, you need to become religious about documenting. Keep a diary. Literally. You document something every day about how your day went. Spend no less than a half hour writing down interactions you have.  I can tell you from personal experience, you will be glad you did because it becomes much harder to misrepresent things when you have record of it and courts just love contemporary diaries versus a couple of forms from your employer.  I would do some of this by hand though (if possible) because hand-written logs are much harder to to accuse of being forged because they'll have different handwriting, ink, etc.  For instance, like keeping a hand-written contents where you have a 2 sentence summary of the day and then spew text on computer so they corroborate.

I'm not exaggerating. Keep a log. I think everyone should, personally.  It usefulness is immeasurable, even just for your own recollection.